# The limit of analytic functions

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $f_i$ are real analytic functions on $\mathbb R^n$ such that for arbitrary partial derivative index $\alpha  \ge 0$, $f_i^\alpha  \to {f^\alpha }$ uniformly, is it necessary that $f$ is an analytic function?

Comment: You say that $\alpha$ is just an index (and I guess, not a power) - then I wail to find how is is used in your statement.

Comment: Are you using $f^{\alpha}$ as notation for a partial derivative of $f$ of arbitrary order? If not, I, too, am puzzled as to how to understand your notation.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity, I have clarified it.

Comment: In mathoverflow this question was discussed. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53557/metric-on-the-space-of-real-analytic-functions